# How to prevent the cover letter from rolling over to the second page?

Tags: fonts, paragraphs, scrlttr2

% Briefvorlage für Privatleute
% Ersteller: Alexey Abel
% Git-Repository: https://github.com/PanCakeConnaisseur/latex-briefvorlage-din-5008
% Basiert auf KOMA-Scripts scrlttr2

```
\documentclass[
% Schriftgröße
fontsize=12pt,
%
% zwischen Absätzen eine leere Zeile einfügen, statt lediglich Einrückung
parskip=full,
%
% Papierformat auf DIN-A4
paper=A4,   
%
% Absender im Briefkopf (ganz oben) rechts ausrichten, standardmäßig links
fromalign=right,
%
% Telefonnummer im Briefkopf anzeigen
fromphone=true,
%
% Faxnnummer im Briefkopf anzeigen
%fromfax=true,
%
% E-Mail-Adresse im Briefkopf anzeigen
fromemail=true,
%
% URL im Briefkopf anzeigen
%fromurl=true,
%
% Faltmarkierungen verbergen
%foldmarks=false,
%
% Briefkopf (Absenderdaten oben rechts) verbergen
%firsthead=off
%
% Die neuste Version von scrlettr2 verwenden 
version=last,
]{scrlttr2}
% Zeichenkodierung des Dokuments ist in UTF-8
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Eurosymbol-Unterstützung
\usepackage{eurosym}
% Das Unicode-Zeichen € als \euro interpretieren.% So kann man direkt € tippen anstatt jedes Mal \euro auszuschreiben.
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{20AC}{\euro}

% Sprache des Dokuments auf Deutsch
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

% Includen von PDFs nach dem Brief, siehe \includepdf unten
\usepackage{pdfpages}

% klickbare Links und E-Mail-Adressen. Paket url kann keine klickbaren,
% deswegen hyperref. Option hidelinks versteckt farbige Umrandungen.
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}



\begin{document}
% Abstand zwischen Schlussgruß und Name vergrößern (alle drei Zeilen auskommentieren)
%\makeatletter
%\@setplength{sigbeforevskip}{3em}
%\makeatother

% Name nach Schlussgruß (unter Unterschrift) nicht nach rechts einrücken
%\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}



% Absendername
\setkomavar{fromname}{Anton Absender}

% Absenderadresse
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Absenderstraße 12\\67890 Aalen}

% Absendertelefonnummer
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+49 123 456 7891}

% Absenderfax
% (oben fromfax=true setzen)
%\setkomavar{fromfax}{+49 222 222 22}

% Absender-E-Mail-Adresse
% der erste Paremeter ist fürs Klicken, der zweite wird angezeigt/gedruckt
\setkomavar{fromemail}{\href{mailto:anton@absender.de}{anton@absender.de}}

% Absender-URL
% (oben fromurl=true setzen)
% eckige Klammern entfernen damit "URL:" erscheint oder dort Alternativtext eintragen
% der erste Parameter ist fürs Klicken, der zweite wird angezeigt/gedruckt
\setkomavar{fromurl}[]{\href{http://absender.de}{absender.de}}



% Ort beim Datum
\setkomavar{place}{Berlin}

% Datum
\setkomavar{date}{\today}

% Betreff
\setkomavar{subject}{Kündigung}



% Kundennummer
%\setkomavar{customer}[\customername]{DE-112233}

% Ihr Zeichen
%\setkomavar{yourref}[\yourrefname]{IZ-12345}

% Ihr Schreiben vom
%\setkomavar{yourmail}[\yourmailname]{1. April 2018}



\begin{letter}{
Empfänger GmbH\\
Empfängerstraße 123\\
12345 Essen
}

\opening{Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,}

Loreß "`ipsum"' 200 € sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam faucibus euismod nibh. Nulla condimentum, odio in vehicula bibendum, tellus libero varius sapien, vel aliquam elit mauris ut leo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla vitae dapibus felis, ut euismod lectus.

Vestibulum at auctor urna, in iaculis lectus. Nullam vitae magna metus. Praesent lacinia massa ac lobortis ullamcorper. Vestibulum laoreet, ligula ut tincidunt auctor, ligula lacus accumsan lectus, vitae aliquet justo diam et risus. Etiam suscipit magna vel velit tristique, quis egestas justo aliquam. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum sit amet elementum lacus, ac nulla.

Loreß "`ipsum"' 200 € sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam faucibus euismod nibh. Nulla condimentum, odio in vehicula bibendum, tellus libero varius sapien, vel aliquam elit mauris ut leo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla vitae dapibus felis, ut euismod lectus.

Vestibulum at auctor urna, in iaculis lectus. Nullam vitae magna metus. Praesent lacinia massa ac lobortis ullamcorper. Vestibulum laoreet, ligula ut tincidunt auctor, ligula lacus accumsan lectus, vitae aliquet justo diam et risus. Etiam suscipit magna vel velit tristique, quis egestas justo aliquam. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum sit amet elementum lacus, ac nulla.

\closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen}

% Post Scriptum
%\ps PS: Ich bin bis März nur telefonisch erreichbar.

% Anlage(n)
% Standardmäßig wird "Anlage(n)" eingefügt, dies kann überschrieben werden, hier mit "Anlagen"
%\setkomavar*{enclseparator}{Anlagen}
%\encl{Kopie des Ausweises}

% Verteiler
%\cc{Bürgermeister, Vereinsvorsitzender}

\end{letter}

% Weitere PDFs können automatisch angefügt werden, z.B. die Ahnänge.
%\includepdf[pages=-]{pfad/zu/weiteren/pdfs/dokument.pdf}
% Pfad ist relativ zu dieser .tex Datei. Mit .. ein Verzeichnis hoch.
% Der pages parameter spezifiziert welche Seiten eingefügt werden.
% Beispiele:
% pages=-               alle Seiten
% pages={1-4}           Seite 1-4
% pages={1,4,5}         Seite 1, 4 und 5
% pages={3,{},8-11,15}  Seite 3, leere Seite, Seite 8-11 und Seite 15

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried smaller font sizes, but I still get 2-page letter. Removing spaces between paragraphs also did not work out as planned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no footer, so you could add class options `firstfoot=false` and `enlargefirstpage`:

```
\documentclass[
%fontsize=12pt,% default
parskip=full,
%paper=A4,% default
fromalign=right,
fromphone=true,
fromemail=true,
%version=last,% default
%DINmtext,<- added
firstfoot=false,% <- added
enlargefirstpage% <- added
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{showframe}% <- to show the page layout
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{20AC}{\euro}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Anton Absender}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Absenderstraße 12\\67890 Aalen}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+49 123 456 7891}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{\href{mailto:anton@absender.de}{anton@absender.de}}
\setkomavar{fromurl}[]{\href{http://absender.de}{absender.de}}
\setkomavar{place}{Berlin}
%\setkomavar{date}{\today}
\setkomavar{subject}{Kündigung}

\begin{letter}{
Empfänger GmbH\\
Empfängerstraße 123\\
12345 Essen
}

\opening{Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,}

Loreß "`ipsum"' 200 € sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam faucibus euismod nibh. Nulla condimentum, odio in vehicula bibendum, tellus libero varius sapien, vel aliquam elit mauris ut leo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla vitae dapibus felis, ut euismod lectus.

Vestibulum at auctor urna, in iaculis lectus. Nullam vitae magna metus. Praesent lacinia massa ac lobortis ullamcorper. Vestibulum laoreet, ligula ut tincidunt auctor, ligula lacus accumsan lectus, vitae aliquet justo diam et risus. Etiam suscipit magna vel velit tristique, quis egestas justo aliquam. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum sit amet elementum lacus, ac nulla.

Loreß "`ipsum"' 200 € sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam faucibus euismod nibh. Nulla condimentum, odio in vehicula bibendum, tellus libero varius sapien, vel aliquam elit mauris ut leo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla vitae dapibus felis, ut euismod lectus.

Vestibulum at auctor urna, in iaculis lectus. Nullam vitae magna metus. Praesent lacinia massa ac lobortis ullamcorper. Vestibulum laoreet, ligula ut tincidunt auctor, ligula lacus accumsan lectus, vitae aliquet justo diam et risus. Etiam suscipit magna vel velit tristique, quis egestas justo aliquam. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum sit amet elementum lacus, ac nulla.

\closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

If you uncomment `DINmtext` in the example above, you get

[image]

Note that `DINmtext` changes the position of the address a bit. So it is only suitable for window envelopes in the sizes C6 and C6/5 (C6 long).

Additionally you could use `parskip=half` instead `parskip=full`.

And you can change the vertical space between the closing text and the signature using

```
\makeatletter
\@setplength{sigbeforevskip}{\baselineskip}
\makeatother
```

(Additional remark: Starting with the next KOMA-Script version (3.26) `\setplength{sigbeforevskip}{\baselineskip}` will work, too.)

Answer (score 0):

The key is `\closing` which eat up a large block of space.  This is not apparent as `\parskip` expands until `\closing` will fit on the first page.

This solution redefines `\closing` to use whatever space is left on the page.  One still needs to use `\footnotesize` for the letter itself.

```
\documentclass[
% Schriftgröße
fontsize=12pt,
%
% zwischen Absätzen eine leere Zeile einfügen, statt lediglich Einrückung
parskip=full,
%
% Papierformat auf DIN-A4
paper=A4,   
%
% Absender im Briefkopf (ganz oben) rechts ausrichten, standardmäßig links
fromalign=right,
%
% Telefonnummer im Briefkopf anzeigen
fromphone=true,
%
% Faxnnummer im Briefkopf anzeigen
%fromfax=true,
%
% E-Mail-Adresse im Briefkopf anzeigen
fromemail=true,
%
% URL im Briefkopf anzeigen
%fromurl=true,
%
% Faltmarkierungen verbergen
%foldmarks=false,
%
% Briefkopf (Absenderdaten oben rechts) verbergen
%firsthead=off
%
% Die neuste Version von scrlettr2 verwenden 
version=last,
]{scrlttr2}
% Zeichenkodierung des Dokuments ist in UTF-8
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Eurosymbol-Unterstützung
\usepackage{eurosym}
% Das Unicode-Zeichen € als \euro interpretieren.% So kann man direkt € tippen anstatt jedes Mal \euro auszuschreiben.
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{20AC}{\euro}

% Sprache des Dokuments auf Deutsch
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

% Includen von PDFs nach dem Brief, siehe \includepdf unten
\usepackage{pdfpages}

% klickbare Links und E-Mail-Adressen. Paket url kann keine klickbaren,
% deswegen hyperref. Option hidelinks versteckt farbige Umrandungen.
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{showframe}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\closing}[1]{{%
    \setparsizes{\z@}{\z@}{\z@ plus 1fil}\par@updaterelative\nobreak\par
    \nobreak\vskip\baselineskip
    \stopbreaks\noindent
    \parbox{\textwidth}{\strut\ignorespaces #1}\par
    \vskip\baselineskip\vfill
    \parbox{\textwidth}{\strut\ignorespaces
      \usekomavar{signature}\ifhmode\scr@endstrut\fi}\par
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
% Abstand zwischen Schlussgruß und Name vergrößern (alle drei Zeilen auskommentieren)
%\makeatletter
%\@setplength{sigbeforevskip}{3em}
%\makeatother

% Name nach Schlussgruß (unter Unterschrift) nicht nach rechts einrücken
%\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}



% Absendername
\setkomavar{fromname}{Anton Absender}

% Absenderadresse
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Absenderstraße 12\\67890 Aalen}

% Absendertelefonnummer
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+49 123 456 7891}

% Absenderfax
% (oben fromfax=true setzen)
%\setkomavar{fromfax}{+49 222 222 22}

% Absender-E-Mail-Adresse
% der erste Paremeter ist fürs Klicken, der zweite wird angezeigt/gedruckt
\setkomavar{fromemail}{\href{mailto:anton@absender.de}{anton@absender.de}}

% Absender-URL
% (oben fromurl=true setzen)
% eckige Klammern entfernen damit "URL:" erscheint oder dort Alternativtext eintragen
% der erste Parameter ist fürs Klicken, der zweite wird angezeigt/gedruckt
\setkomavar{fromurl}[]{\href{http://absender.de}{absender.de}}



% Ort beim Datum
\setkomavar{place}{Berlin}

% Datum
\setkomavar{date}{\today}

% Betreff
\setkomavar{subject}{Kündigung}



% Kundennummer
%\setkomavar{customer}[\customername]{DE-112233}

% Ihr Zeichen
%\setkomavar{yourref}[\yourrefname]{IZ-12345}

% Ihr Schreiben vom
%\setkomavar{yourmail}[\yourmailname]{1. April 2018}



\begin{letter}{
Empfänger GmbH\\
Empfängerstraße 123\\
12345 Essen
}
\footnotesize
\opening{Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,}

Loreß ``ipsum'' 200 € sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam faucibus euismod nibh. Nulla condimentum, odio in vehicula bibendum, tellus libero varius sapien, vel aliquam elit mauris ut leo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla vitae dapibus felis, ut euismod lectus.

Vestibulum at auctor urna, in iaculis lectus. Nullam vitae magna metus. Praesent lacinia massa ac lobortis ullamcorper. Vestibulum laoreet, ligula ut tincidunt auctor, ligula lacus accumsan lectus, vitae aliquet justo diam et risus. Etiam suscipit magna vel velit tristique, quis egestas justo aliquam. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum sit amet elementum lacus, ac nulla.

Loreß "`ipsum"' 200 € sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam faucibus euismod nibh. Nulla condimentum, odio in vehicula bibendum, tellus libero varius sapien, vel aliquam elit mauris ut leo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla vitae dapibus felis, ut euismod lectus.

Vestibulum at auctor urna, in iaculis lectus. Nullam vitae magna metus. Praesent lacinia massa ac lobortis ullamcorper. Vestibulum laoreet, ligula ut tincidunt auctor, ligula lacus accumsan lectus, vitae aliquet justo diam et risus. Etiam suscipit magna vel velit tristique, quis egestas justo aliquam. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum sit amet elementum lacus, ac nulla.

\closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen}

% Post Scriptum
%\ps PS: Ich bin bis März nur telefonisch erreichbar.

% Anlage(n)
% Standardmäßig wird "Anlage(n)" eingefügt, dies kann überschrieben werden, hier mit "Anlagen"
%\setkomavar*{enclseparator}{Anlagen}
%\encl{Kopie des Ausweises}

% Verteiler
%\cc{Bürgermeister, Vereinsvorsitzender}

\end{letter}

% Weitere PDFs können automatisch angefügt werden, z.B. die Ahnänge.
%\includepdf[pages=-]{pfad/zu/weiteren/pdfs/dokument.pdf}
% Pfad ist relativ zu dieser .tex Datei. Mit .. ein Verzeichnis hoch.
% Der pages parameter spezifiziert welche Seiten eingefügt werden.
% Beispiele:
% pages=-               alle Seiten
% pages={1-4}           Seite 1-4
% pages={1,4,5}         Seite 1, 4 und 5
% pages={3,{},8-11,15}  Seite 3, leere Seite, Seite 8-11 und Seite 15

\end{document}
```